# Parse platform, Authenticate a query in a beforeFind trigger

Tags: javascript, mongodb, parse-platform, back4app

I need to authenticate a query in a beforeFind Trigger.
A device that is using Parse is making a `.find()` request, without user, hence unauthenticated.
As the class level permission of this class only allows authenticated queries (can't be changed) even if I make a `.find({useMasterKey:true)}` within the beforeFind trigger, the fetch operation still return a

```
ParseRequestException: Permission denied, user needs to be authenticated.
```

It's important to say that I can't modify the original query, the device's source code can't be changed.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `.find({useMasterKey:true})` should work regardless of the CLP in place. Are you sure it is not working? Do you have any `beforeFind` trigger already in place doing some extra validation?

Comment: Hello David! thanks for answer. Sadly it isn't working and within the class that I'm testing, there isn't any trigger. Just by change, do you have an example of a beforeFind trigger where swap a query for another? If I'm able to swap the query for another one with ```.find({useMasterKey: true})``` my problem would be resolved. Thanks again for your help

Comment: it is not possible to do that. The authorization happens before going to the beforeFind trigger. If you ant to hit the beforeFind trigger, you need to remove the CLP setup and do the authorization by yourself in the trigger. Another option (it's really a workaround) would be an express.js middleware before parse, adding the header.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but as I don't want to break I discarded that approach. Thanks for clarify the issue Davi!